# fastest way to extend a dataframe to match rownames with a list of names

Tags: r, performance, dataframe

My goal is to extend a large dataframe with 200'000 columns in the following way:

I have a list of names in a specific order and I want to extend my original dataframe that has some rownames in common with this list of names such that the extended dataframe has a column with entries exactly as in the list of names and wherever values are missing in the dataframe it should have zeroes.

Minimal reproducible example:

```
entities<-c("C1","C3","C4","C5","E1","E2")
list_of_names<-data.frame(entities)
df<-data.frame(matrix(runif(30), nrow = 3, ncol = 10))
rownames(df)<-c("E1", "C1","C4")


> df
          X1        X2         X3        X4        X5           X6        X7        X8         X9        X10
E1 0.6228159 0.0744723 0.34010018 0.5720812 0.3179460 0.2405663696 0.6198333 0.9367545 0.95729614 0.10671495
C1 0.2435715 0.4046881 0.01714992 0.7806331 0.1113826 0.0003340805 0.1747583 0.5234170 0.07591773 0.76162701
C4 0.3804787 0.8364844 0.85255672 0.8909652 0.0665782 0.7447360640 0.3022620 0.2111203 0.72338528 0.04510692
```

My current way to do it is the following:

```
df_extended<-merge(list_of_names,df,by="entities", all.x=TRUE)
df_extended[is.na(df_extended)] <- 0 

> df_extended
  entities        X1        X2         X3        X4        X5           X6        X7        X8         X9        X10
1       C1 0.2435715 0.4046881 0.01714992 0.7806331 0.1113826 0.0003340805 0.1747583 0.5234170 0.07591773 0.76162701
2       C3 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
3       C4 0.3804787 0.8364844 0.85255672 0.8909652 0.0665782 0.7447360640 0.3022620 0.2111203 0.72338528 0.04510692
4       C5 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
5       E1 0.6228159 0.0744723 0.34010018 0.5720812 0.3179460 0.2405663696 0.6198333 0.9367545 0.95729614 0.10671495
6       E2 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
```

My problem is, that this approach takes too much time to run it for a dataframe having 200'000 columns.
So I would appreciate ideas on alternative approaches to speed it up.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you keep things as matrices and fill a shell container? Takes about 8.6ms for 200k cols on my machine.

```
entities<-c("C1","C3","C4","C5","E1","E2")

# Zero filled container
shell <- matrix(rep(0,length(entities)*10), length(entities),10)
rownames(shell) <- entities

# Data to fill container based on row
m <- matrix(runif(30), nrow = 3, ncol = 10)
rownames(m)<-c("E1", "C1","C4")

# Fill the container
shell[rownames(m),] <- m

shell
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest next `dplyr` approach. It is known that `merge()` can be slow but `dplyr` functions for merging are faster. Here the code:

```
library(dplyr)
#Data
entities<-c("C1","C3","C4","C5","E1","E2")
list_of_names<-data.frame(entities)
df<-data.frame(matrix(runif(30), nrow = 3, ncol = 10))
df$entities<-c("E1", "C1","C4")
#Dplyr
df_extended <- list_of_names %>% left_join(df) %>% replace(is.na(.),0)
```

Output:

```
  entities        X1        X2        X3         X4        X5        X6        X7        X8
1       C1 0.2408607 0.2157208 0.5725859 0.03198733 0.0177955 0.8019684 0.5763417 0.6669142
2       C3 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
3       C4 0.1108980 0.7621460 0.7364038 0.78398394 0.1731782 0.3135231 0.3868382 0.8729648
4       C5 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
5       E1 0.7463177 0.7176220 0.8183764 0.03917483 0.1713210 0.3941307 0.1493993 0.3036486
6       E2 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
         X9       X10
1 0.6231661 0.4644523
2 0.0000000 0.0000000
3 0.8008057 0.5163706
4 0.0000000 0.0000000
5 0.2136563 0.1320652
6 0.0000000 0.0000000
```

Also, testing with a larger dataframe (10.000 columns) this is the performance (including the filling zero stage):

```
system.time({list_of_names %>% left_join(df) %>% replace(is.na(.),0)})
Joining, by = "entities"
   user  system elapsed 
   8.10    0.29    8.96
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to initialize a matrix `v` first and than assign rows in `df` to the matrix based on matched row names, e.g.,

```
v <- matrix(0,nrow = nrow(list_of_names),ncol = ncol(df))
inds <- match(row.names(df),list_of_names$entities)
v[inds,] <- as.matrix(df)
df_extended <- cbind(list_of_names,`colnames<-`(v,names(df)))
```

such that

```
> df_extended
  entities         X1          X2        X3        X4        X5        X6
1       C1 0.51539985 0.008607194 0.1990575 0.4867223 0.4218548 0.2930240
2       C3 0.00000000 0.000000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
3       C4 0.01436587 0.907402197 0.7287643 0.7181379 0.1040645 0.0180306
4       C5 0.00000000 0.000000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
5       E1 0.32819899 0.630265406 0.3515301 0.2034940 0.2318559 0.1730483
6       E2 0.00000000 0.000000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
           X7        X8        X9       X10
1 0.934944232 0.4179499 0.9071613 0.3573136
2 0.000000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
3 0.004799636 0.4632679 0.2883067 0.9171526
4 0.000000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
5 0.470242031 0.0498446 0.8202716 0.2161722
6 0.000000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
```

---

**Performance Test**

Given `df` of `2e6` columns

```
entities<-c("C1","C3","C4","C5","E1","E2")
list_of_names<-data.frame(entities)
df<-data.frame(matrix(runif(30), nrow = 3, ncol = 2e6))
row.names(df)<-c("E1", "C1","C4")
```

we wrap the code to a function `f`,

```
f <- function() {
  v <- matrix(0, nrow = nrow(list_of_names), ncol = ncol(df))
  inds <- match(row.names(df), list_of_names$entities)
  v[inds, ] <- as.matrix(df)
  df_extended <- cbind(list_of_names, `colnames<-`(v, names(df)))
}
```

and then we will see

```
> system.time(f())
   user  system elapsed 
  13.67    1.25   14.93
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to do an assignment with `setdiff`

```
df[setdiff(entities, row.names(df)),] <- 0
df
#          X1         X2        X3        X4         X5        X6        X7         X8        X9       X10
#E1 0.4820426 0.67437639 0.3518886 0.9188573 0.72839443 0.3952201 0.6982616 0.42842151 0.2608569 0.8319276
#C1 0.2529649 0.04766363 0.4089440 0.2825283 0.68637508 0.4778454 0.9156835 0.54208037 0.3971520 0.1528872
#C4 0.2162548 0.70085309 0.8209513 0.9611048 0.05284394 0.5602533 0.6183512 0.05847849 0.1977447 0.8034185
#C3 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
#C5 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
#E2 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
```